# How to install Ubuntu remotely on a windows machine?

Tags: windows, installation, ubuntu-14.04, remote

My client is located in Ireland while I'm in India and he is not very familiar with Linux machines and we need to set up a linux machine so that we can set up an apache server on his machine there. He has windows installed on the machine so is there a way I could install Ubuntu server on the machine by connecting to the Windows machine ?

Comment: Doubtful. The ubuntu installation procedure is quite simple - I'd just send your client a burned installation CD/DVD and a simple set of instructions to follow.